# How can I copy the content of a text file and paste it to another starting at a certain line?

Tags: text-processing

I need to copy the content of a text file and paste it to another text file. The first text file has 10 lines of data and I need them to be copied to the second text file starting at line number 5 (for example). So in the second text file those data should written from line 5 to line 14. How can this be done? Thanks in advance. Consider me as a rookie regarding Linux.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## `head` and `tail` solution

Assume the source file is called `~/a` and the file to be inserted is called `~/b`. We'll put the merged file into `~/c`:

```
head -n 5 ~/a > ~/c
cat ~/b >> ~/c
tail --lines=+6 ~/a >> ~/c
```

- The path `~/` is short hand for your `/home/user` directory name
- head copies the first five lines of file `a` into newly created file `c`
- cat lists the contents of file `b` and appends it to file `c`
- tail appends file `a` starting at line 6 until the end to file `c`

## After verification rename merged file

After verifying that file `c` is merged correctly from files `a` and `b` we'll rename `c` to `a` using:

```
mv ~/c ~/a
```

- `mv` moves file `c` into file `a`. Data isn't physically moved. The file is simply renamed which saves time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked just fine. However is there another way to do this without using a third text file?

Comment: The third file can be renamed to the source file when done. I thought it best to be able to view the file first. I'll add the extra steps to the answer now.

Comment: Or... `(head -n 5 a.txt ; cat b.txt ; tail -n +6 a.txt) > c.txt`

Comment: @JJoao That is a nice one line summary :) For teaching purposes I prefer to use the one line per command method and nested if statements. However for copy and pasting into terminal I love the one liners!

Answer (score 17):

The easiest tool here might be `sed`. To insert `b.txt` into `a.txt` after the 5th line , you could write:

```
sed '5r b.txt' a.txt
```

`sed` reads the file specifiied as argument (`a.txt`) line by line. All lines get reproduced in the output just as they appeared in the input, unless they get altered by a command.

The `5` is an address (line number) at which the following command shall be executed. The command we use is `r`, which takes a file name as argument (here `b.txt`), reads it completely and inserts it into the output after the current line.

As it stands above, this `sed` command line will only print the output to the terminal, without writing to any files. You can either redirect it to a new file (not any of the input files!) using Bash's output redirection:

```
sed '5r b.txt' a.txt > c.txt
```

Or you can directly modify the outer input file `a.txt` by using `sed`'s `-i` (for "in-place") switch. If you write it as `-i.bak`, it will make a backup copy of the original input file with the suffix `.bak` first:

```
sed -i '5r b.txt' a.txt
```

An example:

```
$ cat a.txt 
January
February
March
April
May
October
November
December

$ cat b.txt 
June
July
August
September

$ sed '5r b.txt' a.txt
January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December
```

Answer (score 0):

(Reusing elegant example from @ByteCommander:)

```
awk '1; NR==5 {system("cat b.txt")}' a.txt
```